# Passport Azure AD This expression is not callable

Tags: typescript, passport.js, passport-azure-ad

In the [example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-nodejs-webapi-v2/blob/master/index.js) the following piece of code is used:

```js
import { BearerStrategy } from 'passport-azure-ad'

const bearerStrategy = new BearerStrategy(config, (token, done) => {
        // Send user info using the second argument
        done(null, {}, token);
    }
);
```

This throws the following TS error:
[image]

```
src/index.ts:26:12 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'ITokenPayload' has no call signatures.

26     return done(null, {}, token)
```

Although the code works I was wondering how to avoid this error.

Comment: try `new BearerStrategy(config, (token: ITokenPayload, done: CallableFunction) => ...`

Comment: Yup, that fixed it! If you write it as an answer I'll mark it as sovled. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add types to each of the parameters.

`new BearerStrategy(config, (token: ITokenPayload, done: CallableFunction) => ...`